# Modular congruency application

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to use modular congruences to show that $5=3x^2-4y$ has no solutions on $(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2$.
Here's my attempt:

Take $3x^2\equiv_5 4y$. Then since $2$ is an inverse modulo $5$, $x^2\equiv_58y\equiv_53y$. Hence, $$x^4\equiv_5 4y^2$$
By Fermat's little theorem, since $5$ is prime we require $x^4\equiv_5 1$. However, $4y^2\equiv_5 1$ iff $y^4\equiv_5 1$. So, $x^4\equiv_5y^4$.

Here I'm stuck on how to go further.

Comment: I think there's a much easier way to go about this: try considering the residues mod $4$ instead, it follows very directly that there are no solutions

Comment: The common way is to reduce if $\bmod 4$ which yields $\, 1\equiv -x^2$ so $\,x^2\equiv -1\equiv 3,\,$ contra the linked dupe.

Comment: So what I've done using the first suggestion is write $3x^2\equiv_4 5$, which implies $x^2\equiv_4 3$. Used this formula in addition to $5=3x^2-4y$ to create a matrix and rref the matrix. This gave only one solution $(1, -1/2)$ which is obviously not in $\mathbb Z^2$. That should be good, right?